# post() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'user', 'user_obj', and 'code'

Tags: python, django, oop, django-rest-framework

```
class CodeAPIView(APIView):
   def post(self,request,user,user_obj,code):
    code2 = request.data['code']
    if code2 == code:
        AuthAPIView.login(self,request,user,user_obj)
    else:
        return Response("the code is wrong!")
```

this is my view, and I get an error. How can I fix it?

this is my full view

```
class AuthAPIView(APIView):

def post(self, request, format=None):
    data = request.data

    username = data.get('username', None)
    password = username

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
                code = random_code_generator()
                
            
                Code.objects.create(phone_number=user_obj,code=code)
                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                
                hour = current_time.split(":")[0]

                minute = current_time.split(":")[1]
                send(str(username),code,int(hour),int(minute)+2)
                CodeAPIView.post(self,request,user,user_obj,code)
                return Response("done")



def login(self,request,user,user_obj,code):
    
    login(request, user)
    token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
    return Response(token.key)
    Code.objects.filter(phone_number=user_obj,code = code).delete()
   

   

class CodeAPIView(APIView):
def post(self,request,user,user_obj,code):
    code2 = request.data('code')
    
    if code2 == code:
        AuthAPIView.login(self,request,user,user_obj,code)
    else:
        return Response("the code is wrong!")
```

I try to send an otp to my phone number. I send it . when I wanna enter it for authentication, I use `CodeAPIView`. it needs some data which have been recived from `AuthAPIView`

Comment: How do you call post, what arguments are you sending to the function? Please add the code, where you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong:

the `APIView` class  post method accept argument like this:

```
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: thank you.. would you please write the full code?